# Problemas com acento com PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estou fazendo um formulário PHP, no qual utilizei um javascript num combo.

Então quando seleciono o primeiro `select`, o segundo abre dados diferentes dependendo do que você seleciona primeiro. Até ai ok, funciona.

Exemplo de duas opções diferentes, que usei no combobox dinâmico:

```
var groups=document.banquinho.oferta.options.length
var group=new Array(groups)
for (i=0; i<groups; i++)
group[i]=new Array()

group[0][0]=new Option("--")

group[1][0]=new Option("Erro na parametrização da regra de negocios")

group[2][0]=new Option("BA/SE - Pendência comercial")
group[2][1]=new Option("CO/N - Pendência comercial")
group[2][2]=new Option("CPF não confere com o nome do cliente")
group[2][3]=new Option("Data de nascimento digitada não confere com o CPF do      cliente")
group[2][4]=new Option("Documento não cadastrado no Serasa")
group[2][5]=new Option("Faixa etária não permitida para habilitação")
```

Funciona normal, mas ai quando vou inserir no banco de dados, eu preciso que seja inserido o código, equivalente a cada oferta desse combo.

Como não sei atribuir um valor numérico pra ele diretamente no Javascript (talvez seja até mais fácil), eu acabei fazendo meio que uma gambiarra pra atribuir valor no PHP.

```
$queryComp = "SELECT CodComplemento FROM test.tbl_complemento WHERE Complemento like '%$complemento%' ";
$resultComp = mysqli_query($link, $queryComp);
$numComp = mysqli_num_rows($resultComp);

if ($numComp > 0) 
{
    $dataComplemento    =   mysqli_fetch_array($resultComp);
    $varComplemento     =   $dataComplemento['CodComplemento'];
}
else 
{  
    $message  = 'Complemento não encontrado -> Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()  . "\n";
}
```

Onde o Complemento, é o valor que esta dentro dessa matriz ai em cima, como por exemplo o valor: "BA/SE - Pendência comercial".

Ai quando eu seleciono no combo, uma frase sem acento, ele encontra certinho e atribuiu o valor, mas quando tem acento não funciona! Eu dou um echo na query e aparecem os acentos certinhos e se executo ela diretamente no banco, funciona.

O banco esta em `latin1_swedish_ci` e o formulário em utf-8, alterei a tabela e o banco pra `utf-8` e nada, pra latin de novo e nada, alterei o form para **"charset=ISO-8859-1"** e nada... Fiz tudo que me veio a mente e eu não sei porque não ta rolando.

Subi os dados na tabela por meio daquele script, LOAD, que chamamos o csv e deu certo, aparecem os acentos corretamente. Mas quando vou inserir a palavra **"nâo"** pelo formulário, por exemplo, ela fica incorreta.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Inclua o erro retornado pelo Banco de Dados.

Comment: Não retorna nenhum erro, ele simplesmente não encontra no banco e não atribui nenhum valor. O $numComp = mysqli_num_rows($resultComp) fica zero. 

Outra coisa: Quando insiro a palavra nâo, por exemplo, ela fica incorreta no banco.

Comment: você poderia disponibilizar o esquema do BD? acho que voce precisa modelar melhor o banco para simplificar seu problema

Comment: Você pode deixar o banco como latin_1 e o restante como utf-8... ao menos aqui funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: já experimentou usar a função do PHP utf8_encode($valor) ou html_entity_decode($valor) ?

Comment: Não consigo entrar com o outro login, mas sou eu. Tentei essas funções e não funcionaram @IvanFerrer. Eu terei que montar o banco pra utilização no servidor. O banco já esta estruturado em access, tenho que usar o mesmo esquema no mysql:(. Acho que é algum problema de estrutura, vou montar ele de novo já que é pequeno, pra testar de novo.

Comment: altere o banco latin1_swedish_ci para utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente isso e veja se resolve o problema:

```
ALTER DATABASE `sua_base` CHARSET = UTF8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Isso resolveu, muito obrigada!

Comment: Se foi útil para você, marque a setinha verde. Obrigado.